# ERROR 1086 (HY000) at line 3: File '/var/lib/mysql-files/file_name.csv' already exists

Tags: mysql, database, cron, export-to-csv

I want to retrieve data from the db every 15 minutes. However, the code below does not work as I want. I need to run manually and insert a password every time to retrieve the data even tho I already set the cronjob because the CSV file is not updated every 15 minutes. I need to remove the old CSV files because it said it overwrites the old file. Is there any other code option to retrieve the data from db as CSV to /var/lib/mysql-files? other than using SELECT .. INTO OUTFILES?. Below is my code.

```
use database name;

SELECT *  FROM ... 
INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/file_name.csv'  
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"'  
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I want a code that can help me to export the file from db into csv.

Answer (score 0):

Use dynamic SQL (prepared statement), add a timestamp to the file name providing its uniqueness:

```
-- select database
USE database_name;
-- build statement dynamically
SET @sql := CONCAT(
  'SELECT *  FROM ... INTO OUTFILE ''/var/lib/mysql-files/file_name',
  DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%i_%s'),
  '.csv'' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '',''  ENCLOSED BY ''"'' LINES TERMINATED BY ''\n'';'
  );
-- prepare and execute statement
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DROP PREPARE stmt;
```

Do not forget to quote your code in SELECT part properly (if needed).